# Is php monolog wrap line when write message to log?

Tags: php, logging, monolog

I have a piece of code.

```
class LogApi {

    private $log;
    private $path;
    private $format = array(
        'date' => 'Y-m-d H:i:s',
        'message' => '[%datetime%][%channel%][%level_name%] : %message% %context%',
    );
    private $formatter;

    function __construct() {
        $this->log =  new \Monolog\Logger('Log');
        $this->path = LOG_ADMIN_REDIS_INIT_FILE;
        $this->formatter = new \Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter($this->format['message'], $this->format['date']);

    }

    public function log($path = LOG_ADMIN_REDIS_INIT_FILE, $level = Monolog\Logger::INFO){

        $stream = new \Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler($path, $level);
        $stream->setFormatter($this->formatter);
        $this->log->pushHandler($stream);

        $this->log->addInfo('Mytest', array('name'=>'John'));
    }
}
```

This is the log info:

> [2014-04-04 07:20:41] [Log] [INFO] : Mytest {"name":"John"}

But if I have more logs, everything are in one line.

> [2014-04-04 07:20:41] [Log] [INFO] : Mytest {"name":"John"}[2014-04-04 07:20:41] [Log] [INFO] : Mytest {"name":"John"}[2014-04-04 07:20:41] [Log] [INFO] : Mytest {"name":"John"}

As I am using `StreamHandler` , I look at its source code

```
protected function write(array $record)
{
    if (null === $this->stream) {
        if (!$this->url) {
            throw new \LogicException('Missing stream url, the stream can not be opened. This may be caused by a premature call to close().');
        }
        $errorMessage = null;
        set_error_handler(function ($code, $msg) use (&$errorMessage) {
            $errorMessage = preg_replace('{^fopen\(.*?\): }', '', $msg);
        });
        $this->stream = fopen($this->url, 'a');
        restore_error_handler();
        if (!is_resource($this->stream)) {
            $this->stream = null;
            throw new \UnexpectedValueException(sprintf('The stream or file "%s" could not be opened: '.$errorMessage, $this->url));
        }
    }
    fwrite($this->stream, (string) $record['formatted']);
}
```

Its just append message the log file.

So my question is: Do I need to handle `wrap line` by myself, or monolog already provide function to wrap a line?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does it helps `PHP_EOL.$record['formatted']` in fwrite ?

Comment: I do not want to modify monolog's source code, so may be I can not using advice. But still thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh no, my fault.

```
private $format = array(
    'date' => 'Y-m-d H:i:s',
    'message' => '[%datetime%][%channel%][%level_name%] : %message% %context%',
);
```

Its simple, just config format like this:

```
'message' => '[%datetime%][%channel%][%level_name%] : %message% %context% \n',
```

But I found that not working.

But this works

```
'message' => "[%datetime%][%channel%][%level_name%] : %message% %context% \n",
```

So use **Double quotes**

Comment: A little note on *why* this wasn't working: PHP doesn't parse escaped characters like `\n` when using single quotes. Double quotes *do* parse them. You could also use the constant `PHP_EOL`.